# Rails route that allows POST to a few endpoints and all methods to the rest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails controller with about 60+ actions. I need to change it to allow only POST requests on about 20 actions and any request method for the rest of them.

**Is there a way to do this so I don't have to manually specify ever route that is allowed for all routes?**

This is what I have so far (and works):

```
post_regex = /first_route|second_route/
all_routes_regex = /third_route|fourth_route/
map.connect '/myroute/:id/:action', :controller => 'my_controller', :constraints => {:action => post_regex }, :conditions => { :method => :post }
map.connect '/myroute/:id/:action', :controller => 'my_controller', :constraints => {:action => all_routes_regex }
```

I tried creating something like this but it would just cause a RoutingError.

```
post_regex = /first_route|second_route/
class AllRoutesConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    (request.query_parameters[:action] !~ post_regex)
  end
end
map.connect '/myroute/:id/:action', :controller => 'my_controller', :constraints => {:action => post_regex }, :conditions => { :method => :post }
map.connect '/myroute/:id/:action', :controller => 'my_controller', :constraints => {:action => AllRoutesConstraint }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to do it in the controller instead of in routes.rb, it should be pretty straightforward.  Let all request types through in the routes file:

```
# in config/routes.rb
map.connect '/myroute/:id/:action', :controller => 'my_controller'
```

And then, filter for POST-only actions in the controller.

```
# in app/controllers/my_controller.rb
POST_ONLY_ACTIONS = [:first_route, :second_route]

before_filter :must_be_post, :only => POST_ONLY_ACTIONS

# your actions...

protected

def must_be_post
  unless request.method == "POST"
    raise ActionController::MethodNotAllowed.new("Only post requests are allowed.")
  end
end
```

This gets you the same error and error message that Rails would generate for you if you set the method in routes.rb.

The drawback is that your routes.rb file is no longer the single authoritative source on exactly what requests are permissible.  But since you were trying to remove some of that information (the list of non-POST requests) from the routes file anyway, you might find the tradeoff acceptable.